# Transforming Train argument in Chainer 5

Tags: version-control, autoencoder, chainer

How can I change this train argument(older version code) and use this in trainer extensions. What are the necessary changes to be made to use this code in Chainer: 5.4.0.

```
ValueError: train argument is not supported anymore. Use 
chainer.using_config
```

**[AutoEncoder/StackedAutoEncoder/Regression.py]**(https://github.com/quolc/chainer-ML-examples/blob/master/mnist-stacked-autoencoder/net.py)

**[Train.py]**(https://github.com/quolc/chainer-ML-examples/blob/master/mnist-stacked-autoencoder/train_mnist_sae.py)

```
for epoch in range(0, n_epoch):
    print('  epoch {}'.format(epoch+1))
    perm = np.random.permutation(N)
    permed_data = np.array(input_data[perm])

    sum_loss = 0
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(0, N, batchsize):
        x = chainer.Variable(permed_data[i:i+batchsize])
        y = chainer.Variable(permed_data[i:i+batchsize])

        optimizer.update(model, x, y)
        sum_loss += float(model.loss.data) * len(y.data)
    end = time.time()
    throughput = N / (end - start)
    print('    train mean loss={}, throughput={} data/sec'.format(sum_loss 
/ N, throughput))
    sys.stdout.flush()

# prepare train data for next layer
x = chainer.Variable(np.array(train_data))
train_data_for_next_layer = cuda.to_cpu(ae.encode(x, train=False).data)
```

In errors it points out to two different sections:
1. optimizer.update(model, x, y)
2. prepare train data for next layer second line where they mismatch the number of nodes in each layer. The error code is given below.

```
InvalidType: 
Invalid operation is performed in: LinearFunction (Forward)

Expect: prod(in_types[0].shape[1:]) == in_types[1].shape[1]
Actual: 784 != 250
```

Comment: I have edited the question to add the error messages of mismatching...

Answer (score 2):

As to train argument, the details are written here: https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/upgrade_v2.html

train argument is used by dropout in v1, but now Chainer uses config to manage its phase: in training or not.
So, there are two things to do.
First, remove train arguments from scripts.
Second, move inference code in the context.

```
with chainer.using_config(‘train’, False):
    # define the inference process
```

> prepare train data for next layer second line where they mismatch the number of nodes in each layer.

Could you share the error messages?